# Problem implementing Native Ads using 'react-native-fbads:v7.0.5' library

Tags: typescript, react-native, facebook-audience-network, facebook-ads, react-native-fbads

I'm facing problem implementing NativeAds using this library.
I've followed what the docs say ([Link here](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-fbads/tree/v7.0.5)), but what I have in the code is deferent from what the documentation says.

**1- I created a file for the Native Ad component :**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {
  withNativeAd,
  AdIconView,
  TriggerableView,
  MediaView,
} from 'react-native-fbads';

const AdComponent = ({ nativeAd }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <AdIconView style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} />
      <MediaView style={{ width: 160, height: 90 }} />
      <TriggerableView>
        <Text>{nativeAd.description}</Text>
      </TriggerableView>
    </View>
  );
};

export const MyNativeAd = withNativeAd(AdComponent);
```

**2- Inside the screen where I want to display this ad :**

```
import { InterstitialAdManager, AdSettings, NativeAdsManager } from 'react-native-fbads';
import { MyNativeAd } from 'components/NativeBanner';
...
let nativeAdsManager: NativeAdsManager =  new NativeAdsManager(PLACEMENT_ID);
...
export const Myscreen = () => {
  <View>
    <MyNativeAd adsManager={nativeAdsManager} nativeAd={???????} />
  </View>
}
```

As you can see in the code above, I must provide a `nativeAd` property to the `MyNativeAd` component. I don't know what I should put there. As the documentation do not mention anything related to this property. Any assistance how to correctly use the Native Ads would be appreciated.